# Crash when initializing NSMutableAttributedString that is empty

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

I have the following code in a playground:

```
import Foundation

let str = NSMutableAttributedString()
```

When I run it, it crashes with the following output:

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1bb4d7d84)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001bb4d7d84 AppKit`-[NSApplication _crashOnException:] + 324
    frame #1: 0x00000001bb4d7a9c AppKit`-[NSApplication reportException:] + 580
    frame #2: 0x00000001bb581fb4 AppKit`uncaughtErrorProc + 156
    frame #3: 0x00000001b87010bc CoreFoundation`__handleUncaughtException + 800
    frame #4: 0x00000001b83c8314 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 132
    frame #5: 0x00000001b84e1ea4 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
    frame #6: 0x00000001b84e4c1c libc++abi.dylib`__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*) + 36
    frame #7: 0x00000001b84e4bc8 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw + 140
    frame #8: 0x00000001b83bff6c libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw + 420
    frame #9: 0x00000001b94e4718 Foundation`-[NSRLEArray objectAtIndex:effectiveRange:] + 188
    frame #10: 0x00000001b94f70fc Foundation`-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString attribute:atIndex:effectiveRange:] + 52
    frame #11: 0x0000000108e76a78 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol752 + 80
    frame #12: 0x0000000108e76c7c PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol756 + 20
    frame #13: 0x0000000108e73510 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol614 + 60
    frame #14: 0x0000000108e73960 PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol627 + 20
    frame #15: 0x0000000108e6e98c PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol487 + 432
    frame #16: 0x0000000108e7450c PlaygroundLogger`___lldb_unnamed_symbol655 + 376
    frame #17: 0x0000000108e6d864 PlaygroundLogger`playground_log_hidden + 260
    frame #18: 0x000000010463434c $__lldb_expr26`main at MyPlayground6.playground:3:5
    frame #19: 0x00000001042863d8
```

This is a fresh playground, not attached to any project(so it's not an extension issue). I'm perplexed and stuck. I did recently upgrade to XCode 14. I've tried restarting XCode, and my laptop, but no luck. Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful but it doesn't crash using Xcode 14.1 beta 3. _Edit_ I had version 14.0 beta 6 installed as well and there it crashes for me too so it looks like this will be resolved in 14.1

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm on 14.0.1, which seems to be the latest version. Where can I get a beta of 14.1?

Comment: Nevermind. Found it through a direct download on https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I downloaded 14.1 and can confirm that the code is now working, so your initial idea that this is a 14.0 issue seems to be confirmed. Thanks for the help!